# I got this QR code and what does this random text from qr code means?

Tags: cryptography, qr-code

[QR code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeQrA.jpg)

and this is the text I got after scanning : 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#QR5315900021

Comment: Cracking random ciphertexts is off-topic, I'm afraid. Please take a look at the [help] pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It consists of two portions. The first portion is a base64 encoded binary blob. The second portion is a version identifier. The identifier is "QR5315900021". The binary blob is, in hex:

```
0000000 f714 d8d7 1fa3 f2e5 9cb9 8ce9 5e02 7813  
0000020 1577 ff45 3345 4216 58c9 bfae 2a35 33d8  
0000040 4ffd c5ea 86c6 a128 77e2 c73a 0117 4564  
0000060 19ed b0b2 5029 6e65 8a27 3f33 7cca 0965  
0000100 bb62 c933 83ea 3dde af22 d197 7c62 c389  
0000120 61fe 2cf9 f1ec ad4e edeb 0300 62f5 1211  
0000140 48aa ce25 1bb7 6449 f66d 61c8 7950 add0  
0000160 287d 5af8 2b41 3323 a996 9e6f f9f8 2894  
0000200 7333 a49a 146c 9616 c962 1bf9 025b a255  
0000220 157c 6d70 5b6a 3a40 daa7 b080 b1a3 8309  
0000240 766f 597e a2f5 6375 cf5e 26bb f961 0b0a  
0000260 1a59 9979 e502 6a57 f2ed 195e a8e6 266b  
0000300 7b39 eda4 9bde cd93 f5ff d0b1 1fbc 924d  
0000320 3d5b 2e37 cd18 f38b 1cee e96b 8e8c aa0c  
0000340 70c0 e7d4 c979 73ac daec 7241 4195 c273  
0000360 e4a8 be40 9efb af97 9d21 b77c f8eb a184  
0000400 bdec 5e60 bccc e00c 8e34 0c43 31bf 5848  
0000420 a9b2 4a73 1438 69a5 02a7 880d c113 40d0  
0000440 cfa2 e316 fe8a 1d6d c145 7f4e 4a25 3811  
0000460 72b1 68f5 21b8 d901 5bb9 a5c4 018a ac9f  
0000500 a3f9 f21a 8b66 f2ab b1d8 7e57 7481 1f26  
0000520 c73b 2db3 14ac ec60 0b46 37ea 8461 9e26  
0000540 3ef7 6ac3 10c0 52b1 bb24 b9af 9107 f18a  
0000560 34c2 ac07 b7a7 ab9f a229 9b02 f285 9953  
0000600 b89a dbe2 ea4f a59a 0b70 2430 79bc 973c  
0000620 56f8 6c82 2476 f533 d5f2 d65c e9a2 81ee  
0000640 b798 da13 10ab bf9b b8fe 0d1a 36e5 2945  
0000660 4b04 0465 674b f3b7 0abc 6a6b b2ec 468b  
0000700 682a a7ef 5e2a e698 4050 ec21 8618 adff  
0000720 24d0 a36d 253e d1d1 0807 5dfe 4e1d b610  
0000740 4da5 0409 32ac 4e1b ff6d f804 c842 910a  
0000760 6fe8 16f3 6f25 63e1 dfa9 15d5 bfed c3ba  
0001000 69c4 b36e d103 4706 c1b7 d07d 0de3 5e25  
0001020 fd0b 5441 0e2d 15c9 86c9 7d37 0b40 2382  
0001040 f670 c4d0 8e14 0614 0f0c 5f0d 4801 ed83  
0001060 ca00 10e1 c6b3 4ede 7de2 25a7 a7ef a525  
0001100 d18d 64ca 9a10 12e5 10e7 e37b 7227 3097  
0001120 12d1 77c6 2569 8f6e 2ac4 a098 5c7a 0f72  
0001140 80d6 2fa7 7391 4641 653a d44e 7108 cb14  
0001160 bbc1 1677 6aa7 4500 7464 9d94 f27d 0b84  
0001200 80ab e40b afc7 deb5 d37d 9f70 1d55 0c0b  
0001220 2631 407a 3640 ec29 e4cb d555 d92d 637b  
0001240 207b fd12 8d24 177a adb9 51b1 2908 d417  
0001260 4984 1033 40af c555 c7d3 711b fa0d 8fbf  
0001300 981a 3ff8 c32b c4ac 38ce de99 376c a347  
0001320 6c8e f660 f009 43fb 7d5d a5c5 979e aafc  
0001340 63ba 5c83 0eb6 5fa2 7344 edb4 02ad 244a  
0001360 b55c 6f10 1669 bd0e b16a eaba be84 1a99  
0001400 1e39 d04e dad0 e082 3a0c b90a 936c a07a  
0001420 bbf4 91bc 0419 1d2e ea37 9179 83e3 ca9d  
0001440 14b9 fecf fd41 7928 c57c 5a96 acdc 556b  
0001460 29f4 3b99 d3c7 ad55 6f5d 73b9 549a 5400
```

This appears to be the payload for an unreserved train ticket in India, but you'll have to ask the issuer for further details.

Comment: Please read the last sentence of my answer, particularly the part after the "but".